# How to lessen the python path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

Due to something I did I have to run my python3 as

`$sudo /home/mayuresh/anaconda3/bin/python file_name.py`

I tried to set the python path but it doesn't help can someone please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I tried to set the python path*. Show what you tried. If it was done correctly it should work.

Comment: BTW: Ask yourself if you need `sudo` and why. Apart from that, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry for sudo, I needed it because file needed permission... I will keep in mind next time to be more precise with my questions... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you did something like this:

```sh
export PYTHON_PATH=/path/to/python3
sudo /home/mayuresh/anaconda3/bin/python file_name.py
```

This way, `sudo` doesn't use the environment variables of your context. You have to define the environment variables in the `sudo` context.

Either with `-E` option, which means "use current environment variables":

```sh
export PYTHON_PATH=/path/to/python3
sudo -E /home/mayuresh/anaconda3/bin/python file_name.py
```

Or by setting them in sudo command:

```sh
sudo PYTHON_PATH=/path/to/python3 /home/mayuresh/anaconda3/bin/python file_name.py
```